# can we use .project on mongodb when using axios? (goal being to filter some spcifics fields from export)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

this is my first question on this wonderful site, as usually I always found someone who asked before me :)

I have inherited a code and try to make it evolve and you will see in the way I ask that I am not familiar at all with this code... This is for my website, developed in REACT and the database is `MongoDB`. Here is the get function getting all the data from the `MongoDB`, filtered on relevant announces (it is not the exact .then, I simplified it to shorten the post):

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.api_url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
});

export const getAnnounces = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axiosInstance
      .get("/announces?archived=false&status=publique")
      .then(response => resolve({type: ADVERT_FOUND, announces: response.data})
```

My issue is that I would like to define a function getting all information except the images (which are in the collection and in some case increase the size of the export without added value). I tried this, but unsuccessfully

```
export const getAnnounces = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axiosInstance
      .get("/announces?archived=false&status=publique", { project: {images:0} })
      .then(response => resolve({type: ADVERT_FOUND, announces: response.data})
```

Does someone know if it is possible to use .project or .projection with `axios`... if not, any `idea/suggestion` how to manage this?

Edit:
thanks to feedback below, I went to the API, found the definition of getAnnounces in a way I better understand:

```
const getAnnounces = (req, res, next) => {const { filter, skip, limit, sort, projection } = aqp(req.query);
Announces.find(filter)
```

I changed simply to this, and it works perfectly!

```
Announces.find(filter,{images:0})
```

Thanks,
Antoine

Comment: It seems that you need to look at the code in the api which provides the endpoint `/announces`, what does it expect so it doesn't return images ?

Comment: Thanks. I am now digging the API and even if not yet fixed, I think I found where I have to try to put the .project()

Comment: Edited with the solution I found. Effectively, I was not looking to the correct place...

Comment: Are you sure that no one need images from this endpoint ? If you do need images sometimes, then it is better to make it configurable by the client, for example : `/announces?archived=true&$fields[images]=0`

Comment: Hello Stephane, in fact the development was done by several persons, and the API was already done in a way allowing to get what you need for the front to optimize a bit the code. For example, a gettopthree is already developped and can be used when needed. Anyway I keep in mind this possibility to make it configurable as you said in case we need many different call (which is not the case today, we have only two pages calling, the main page, and the page with the list of all announces sorted or filtered). Thanks again